# how to calculate the current at the 4 brushless motor

Tags: voltage, current

[image]

Motors specification:

380KV

throttle: 50%

Amps 1.6A

Power: 23.68W

thrust: 430G

RPM:2600

Efficiency:18.16 G/W

### Temp: 45C

Battery Voltage: 14.8V

Voltage stepped down from 18.62V to 14.8V

Propellers: 15x5CF

### Net thrust= 1308 g ( weight of the project)

I would like to know how to calculate the current and the voltage that are marked in the circuit. please let me know if you need more information

**[Datasheet Link](http://store-en.tmotor.com/goods.php?id=354)**

Comment: How is efficiency defined here? Efficiency is normally expressed in percent. Does G/W indicate grams of thrust per watt with the specified propellor? What are the units for Kv, RPM/Volt? Is the motor current and Kv expressed in terms of controller inputs?

Comment: @Charles Cowie i took these values from the datasheet. (http://store-en.tmotor.com/goods.php?id=354)

Comment: 'G' is not an SI unit. If it's grams then it should be 'g'.

Comment: "G/W" is hogwash.

Comment: It's possible to deduce in the link that the G means [g-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force) (acceleration) and W is Watt. The efficiency in this sense is how much lift you get per W. It shows several different motors with different efficiencies. So 1 *hogwash* (G/W) would be equal to an acceleration of ~9.8 m/s per watt. So feed 1 watt in and you will cancel out the gravitational force.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the data sheet lists voltage, current and power data points for the input of the electronic speed controller (ESC). The data is based on the listed propellors. For 50% throttle, the current is 1.6 amps per motor and 6.4 amps total. At 100% throttle, the current would be 7.5 amps each and 30 amps total.

The current taken from the MPPT controller and the battery would depend on the battery's state of charge and the level of solar panel illumination. With high illumination and low battery charge, the MMPT controller would supply all of the motor current. With low illumination and high battery charge, the battery would supply all of the current. The transition may be difficult to characterize.

In the diagram presented in the question, M1 thru M4 actually each represent the combination of ESC, motor and propellor as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

Im = I1 + I2 + I3 + I4

If you know that these currents are equal, then simply

Im = I1 * 4

Your 'current rating' says 1.6A, but we don't know if that is the operating point that you are using or if that is simply a maximum.  If it is a maximum, then your maximum Im would be 6.4A.

Voltage will be determined by your MPPT converter and the current charge level of your battery.  If your battery is charged, you could be around 14.5V.  If not, then you could be as low as 11V.